# Android Unknown Memory Usage

Tags: insufficient-memory, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I have been having a problem with my Android 2.3.3 Samsung Galaxy S, that it was shutting 2 essential applications down: messaging app and call protocol. I have been tracing the cause of that by looking phone logs with SDK in eclipse. I have spotted this error:
I/ActivityManager(524): Low Memory: No more background processes.

So I assume this is the reason for the crash... eitherway I want to understand, why I do not have enough memory. I do not have many apps running in the background and I am very careful with what I am installing. I have looked at the memory allocation in eclipse DDMS view and there were:
217 MB (75 %) was unknown,
8 MB (3 %) free
1 MB (0 %) buffers
35 MB (12 %) inactive
14 MB (5 %) slab
12 MB (4 %) page tables.

Of course now I want to know what that unknown place means. Because if I force close some system services or app services I can only reduce unknown allocation down to 55 - 60 %.

How can I find out what this unknown memory usage is?